# ImageView hides TextView when is in movement animation

Tags: java, android

I have a problem namely the ImageView (`imageView`) hides TextView (`tvAppName`) when is in animation movement. This is my Code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAppName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CalcResultStyle"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_rest" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvAppName"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_for_image_view"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CalcResultStyle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleX="1.2"
            android:scaleY="1.2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAppFeatures"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_for_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CalcResultStyle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/funkcje_programu"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_rest" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAppDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CalcResultStyle"
            android:text="@string/info_dodatkowe"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvAppFeatures"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_rest" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVersion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_for_image_view"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CalcResultStyle"
            android:text="v: 3.4.5"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvAppDescription"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_rest" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code of animation if it turns out to be important:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:toXScale="3.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="3.0"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" >
</scale>

<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:startOffset="5000"
    android:fromXScale="3.0"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:fromYScale="3.0"
    android:toYScale="0.5"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" >
</scale>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I need to switch the order of views. First declaration of imageView and then tvAppName.